# Node losing the reference to another object when passed through function

Tags: java, oop

I'm working with double-ended queues for an assignment, and we're running into an issue where the object reference is disappearing from a node after being passed through an extremely simple method.

Some important definitions:

```
class Node {
    String s;
    Node prev;
    Node next;

    ...

}

class Sentinel extends Node {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
   //Constructor uses that of Node
}

class Deque {
    Sentinel start;

    ...
}
```

One method we are writing removes a Node from a deque, based on the given string.

In deque:

```
public void removeSorted(String toRemove) {
    // System.out.println(this.start);
    // System.out.println(this.start.next);
    this.start.next.removeSorted(toRemove);
}
```

The commented out println's show the correct Sentinel and Node.

Then, in Node:

```
public void removeSorted(String toRemove) {
    if (this.s.equals(toRemove)) {
        // System.out.println(this.prev);
        // System.out.println(this.prev.next);
        this.prev.next = this.next;
        this.next.prev = this.prev;
    } else if (this.s.compareTo(toRemove) > 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("String does not exist in these nodes!");
    } else {
        this.next.removeSorted(toRemove);
    }
}
```

The println for `this.prev` outputs the Sentinel on the first recursion, as expected. However, this.prev.next outputs null instead of the Node.

This function only fails when trying to remove the first Node, directly after the Sentinel. If you try to remove any other Node, it works correctly, and trying to call `this.prev.next` results in a non-null answer.

Why does the reference disappear when passing to the function (immediately after), since we've shown that the reference is there directly before calling the function?

Comment: Why do you have this `Sentinel` anyway, why not just `Node start;` with `start==null` when list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Either your question code is wrong, or you have same fields in both `Node` and in `Sentinel`. This means, that these two are different:

- `start.next` is `next` field of Sentinel class, which *hides* field with same name from Node class.
- `start.next.prev.next` is also a field of `start`, but now it is the field of Node class, because you access it through Node reference.

Remove `prev` and `next` from Sentinel. Actually remove the whole Sentinel, it looks like you use to to "remove" the `String s`, which is impossible, you can't "remove" super class fields. Or if you need/want sentinel, see below for alternative design.

Also, this demonstrates why you should use *getters* and *setters* instead of accessing fields directly... Your IDE probably has nice refactoring tool to add getters etc (right click on field, see "Refactor" submenu), use it! And if your IDE does not have that, switch to one which does (I prefer NetBeans, but Eclipse and IntelliJ are worthy too), writing Java without such an IDE is an exercise in masochism...

---

Also, in Java avoid that kind of inheritance. You should probably have this kind of overall design:

```
interface NodeInterface {...}
public class Node implements NodeInterface {...}
public class Sentinel implements NodeInterface {...}
```

Then in the `NodeInterface`, define getters and setters, which should take as parameters as well as return `NodeInterface` type. `Sentinel` class would not support all interface methods of course, so those methods can either `return null;`/do nothing, or [`throw new IllegalStateException("Sentinel does not support Xxxx.");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) depending on method and if calling that method for sentinel is bug in calling code or not (better start with throwing exception).

If this is school work and you have not gone over interfaces yet, then replace `interface NodeInterface` with `class NodeBase` (preferably abstract), but in "real world" this would be bad code, because Java does not support multiple inheritance.